# How to do graph with multi colored line

Tags: javascript, graph, plot, jqplot

[image]

Hello fellow guys. I want to draw (zoomable) graphs like this on canvas, with this library,
because it has all needed functions.

http://www.jqplot.com/

But I am open to all other libraries but they have to be free.

I (think) know how to find intersection points but I don't know how to draw those, because I think I should modify/rewrite library to do this.

Anyon got suggestions? The picture of graph is included, it might seem simple to draw but I assure you ,it's not as simple as it looks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have the same problem and I'm planning to use AmCharts :http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/
See the demos : http://www.amcharts.com/demos/